# Using Generate Block/ Loop to Make a Ripple Carry Adder

Tags: loops, for-loop, verilog, xilinx-ise

I've already done searches here and found some insight, but some of the concepts about using this kind of loop elude me. Here are my modules for the Half-Adder and Full-Adder:

```
module HalfAdder( A, B, Cout, S );
    input  A, B;
    output Cout, S;

    assign Cout = A & B;
    assign S = A ^ B;

endmodule


module FullAdder(FA_A, FA_B, Cin, FA_S, Cout);
    input  FA_A, FA_B, Cin;
    output FA_S, Cout;

    wire ha0_S, ha0_C, ha1_C;

    HalfAdder ha0( .A(   FA_A  ),
                    .B(   FA_B  ),
                    .Cout(ha0_C ),
                    .S( ha0_S )
                    );

    HalfAdder ha1( .A(   Cin   ),
                    .B(   ha0_S ),
                    .Cout(ha1_C ),
                    .S( FA_S  )
                    );

    assign Cout = ha0_C | ha1_C;

endmodule
```

And here is my RCA code:

```
module RCA8(A_8, B_8, Cin, Cout, S_8);
input  [7:0] A_8, B_8;
input  Cin;
output Cout;
output [7:0] S_8;

wire   [8:0] c;

assign c[0] = Cin;

genvar i;
generate
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i=i+1) 
    begin : make_fadders
        FullAdder fa(   .FA_A( A_8[i] ),
                            .FA_B( B_8[i] ),
                            .Cin(  c[i]   ),
                            .FA_S( S_8[i] ),
                            .Cout( c[i+1] )
                            );
    end
endgenerate

assign Cout = c[8];

endmodule
```

I'm trying to get the simulator (iSim) to run. When I do check syntax it works, but when I try to generate a programming file it fails and when I run Mapping it returns a bunch of warnings. The iSim says error 861: failed to link the design. Doesn't Mapping have to do with that?

One thing I don't really understand is that in the implementation and/or simulation view, it only shows one fullAdder module in the RCA's drop down tree. Should it show 8? Or is that not how this works?

I really want to make this work, because the alternative is making 8 fadders by hand (as the assignment shows...) as opposed to learning how to use this useful tool.

Other details: Windows 10, using 32-bit Project Navigator Xilinx 14.7

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this link.  Renaming a file called collect2.exe may resolve your issue.

[Xilinx Installation and troubleshooting](http://www.cecs.uci.edu/~qpdang/dglogic/digital-design-101-lab/xilinx-information/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I still need some answers on how the generate block works, though... is there any potential problems with my implementation?

Comment: Based on your code, I would expect to see 8 make_fadder instances.  Each make_fadder instance will have 1 FullAdder within it.  Is that not what you are seeing?

Comment: @rub3z Look at the KamilRymarz' answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. After elaboration simulation tree should look like this:

```
RCA8
  make_fadder[0]
    fa
  make_fadder[1]
    fa
  .
  .
  .
  make_fadder[7]
    fa
```

I've checked it with Vivado simulator and Aldec Riviera-PRO.